# Schemas/databases in accumulo

Tags: mysql, oracle, hbase, accumulo

What is equivalent of mysql's databases or oracle's users or hbase's namespaces in accumulo ? Does accumulo have something like that or all tables are in the same collection/schema/database?

Answer (score 0):

Accumulo [added namespaces in 1.6.0](https://accumulo.apache.org/release/accumulo-1.6.0/#table-namespaces). Documentation on the feature is currently sparse, but the feature is exposed [in the API](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/1.9.2/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Connector.html#namespaceOperations--).